# how to check failure of constructor with exception disabled

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, constructor

In our code base, we do not use c++ exceptions, meaning "`-fno-exceptions`" in gcc compile option (please note this is our company's policy, so no need to argue that). however, in such case, how to check the failure of a constructor from the standard library that throws exceptions. I have read some SO posts, but still have no clear idea. As example, in c++11, `std::regex("pattern")` 
can throw an regex_error exception. If I have the following code:

```
class Wrapper {
public:
    bool create(std::string pattern) {
      try {
        m_regex = std::regex(pattern);
        m_state = true;
      } catch (std::regex_error& e) {
        //handle error case
        m_state = false;
      }
    }
private:
    std::regex m_regex;
    bool m_state;
}
```

Note: 
`m_regex = std::regex(pattern);`

will call

```
explicit basic_regex(const CharT* s, flag_type f = std::regex_constants::ECMAScript)
```

that can throw exception and move assign operator

```
basic_regex& operator=(basic_regex&& __rhs) noexcept
```

Now, with no option of using exception, how could we check the failure of std::regex's constructor?

```
class Wrapper {
public:
    create(std::string pattern) {
        m_regex = std::regex(pattern);
        // now, how to check? 
        // if (m_regex)?
        m_state = true;
    }
private:
    std::regex m_regex;
}
```

I did not find there is any state in std::regex that could indicate the failure.

option 1: Can I assume if the regex constructor fails, abort() will occurs, then the following statement `m_state = true` will not be executed? I checked, it seems the abort() usually happens with exception enabled, but no catch used. so this is wrong.

option 2: Can I use `std::regex* ptr_regex = new std::regex("pattern")`, and check the nullness of ptr_regex?

Comment: You cannot. If you are not allowed to use exceptions (even just for catching), you have to avoid to use STL.

Comment: As @Gonmator says, except it's not just the STL: you have to avoid most every part of the C++ standard library, including, in particular, the regular expressions.

Comment: One good solution to "our company does not permit exceptions", unless that is for very good reasons such as very-low-resources embedded programming, or to deal with legacy code base (this is how it is in Google), is to find work elsewhere, if possible. For, with one important policy made by incompetents, chances are that the rest is just as ungood. The same applies when e.g. the chief executive reveals lack of a working ethics compass: that's likely to have influenced almost all of the organization.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, yeah, unfortunately, it falls into one (actually both) of the good reasons you mentioned. I really searching some work around on the internet, but so far still clueless.

Answer (score 2):

This is a somewhat unsolved problem and [one of the big open problems discussed by SG14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0364r0.pdf), the 'Low Latency' study group of the committee.

As far as the standard is concerned, this is simply undefined. Exceptions are not optional and it is unspecified what happens if you switch them off. Hence the standard library usually offers no alternative way of handling errors. There is currently a tendency towards mitigating this somewhat in future proposals. For instance, the current Filesystem TS has non-throwing overloads that return an error code for all functions that can throw an exception. It might be possible to provide non-throwing alternatives for the existing standard library facilities in a similar way, but that is exactly what SG14 is trying to figure out.

As of now, the important question is: What does *your* compiler do if it encounters a `throw` (or `try`/`catch`) when compiling with exceptions disabled? As mentioned before, the standard does not specify this at all, so any solution here will be necessarily non-portable. Chances are you won't be able to detect or recover from an error indicated by a library through a `throw`, so if you cannot rule out beforehand that an exception will be thrown, you probably want to steer clear of throwing functions (and hence, most of the standard library).

Hopefully, this situation will improve in the future.

Comment: yeah, we are really stuck on this. But we have to find some solutions or work around, as we or our customers could not wait for the committee.

Comment: @pepero I feel your pain. You might want to keep an eye open for alternative implementations. Many vendors have come up with their own implementation of standard library facilities for this and other reasons. 'Embedded STL' is a good starting keyword for an internet search. Sometimes Boost offers implementations with additional guarantees. Unfortunately, I don't know of any implementation for `std::regex` that would solve the problem from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Create a library whose purpose is to wrap exception-requiring `std` utilities.

This library *is* compiled with exceptions enabled.

It either stores the equivalent of an `optional<std::regex>` (for example).  It provides possibly-failing constructors that (within the library's `.cpp` stuff) invoke the constructor, then try/catch and turn failure into an empty `regex`.

If there are other operations that can throw, it wraps them simularly in methods that have error return paths.  Maybe they return `std::experimental::expected<T, error_information>`.

You must be careful with the ODR and linking between this library and code compiled with an exception-disabled `std` library, as inline functions will differ between them.  I do not know the details of how to avoid this problem.  On some platforms, std library functions may be dynamically linked, and you could load the wrong function compiled the wrong way.  Again, I don't know how to solve that.

From what I can tell from a very very quick google, the bloat and from one library with exceptions enabled should be mostly restricted to scale with the size of that library.  Test this.